# Tradingview ATR pine editor

Tags: algorithm, stock, trading, pine-script

I need to calculate ATR take profit ( TP1, TP2, TP3) and stop loss (SL) on the exact candle as entry is. I can't find out how to avoid ATR movement with price moves. 
I'm using this code right now, but its calculating latest price:

```
strategy.exit("TP1", "Short", qty_percent = 60, limit=atrMinus1)
strategy.exit("TP2", "Short", qty_percent = 20, limit=atrMinus2)
strategy.exit("TP3", "Short", qty_percent = 20, limit=atrMinus3)
strategy.exit("SL", "Short, stop = atrStop)
```

Picture shows what I'm looking for

[image: picture]

Comment: What are your BUY and SELL conditions?

Comment: Hello, I dont want to reveal my strategy. Maybe you could describe solution with some kind of example :)